# Virtual COM Port STM32 and Qt Serial Port

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, usb, stm32

My aim is to enable communication via USB CDC HS on STM32 with Ubuntu 20.04 based PC in Qt app created in QtCreator.

So far I've managed to run communication via UART and everything is working fine. Then I decided to switch to USB and I still can read incoming data (but only in CuteCom) and in my Qt app nothing appears.

To be honest I have no idea what is going on and where to look for mistakes. Here I put the code:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()
{
 if (ui->comboBoxDevices->count() == 0){
     this->addToLogs("No devices found.");
             return;
 }
 QString portName = ui->comboBoxDevices->currentText().split(" ").first();
 this->device->setPortName(portName);
 this->device->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
 this->device->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
 this->device->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
 this->device->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
 this->device->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

 if(device->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
     this->addToLogs("Port opened. Setting the connection params...");
     this->addToLogs("UART enabled.");
     qDebug() << "Writing down the parameters...";
     qDebug() << "Baud rate:" << this->device->baudRate();
     qDebug() << "Data bits:" << this->device->dataBits();
     qDebug() << "Stop bits:" << this->device->stopBits();
     qDebug() << "Parity:" << this->device->parity();
     qDebug() << "Flow control:" << this->device->flowControl();
     qDebug() << "Read buffer size:" << this->device->readBufferSize();
     qDebug() << "Read buffer size:" << this->device->portName();
     connect(this->device, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readFromPort()));
 } else {
     this->addToLogs("The port can not be opened.");
 }
```

And the readFromPort() function:

```
void MainWindow::readFromPort()
{
    while(this->device->canReadLine()){
        QString line = this->device->readLine();
        qDebug() << line;
        QString terminator = "\r";
        int pos = line.lastIndexOf(terminator);
        qDebug()<<line.left(pos);
        this->addToLogs(line.left(pos));
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what might be wrong or not set properly? Would be thankful for all help.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, in my code I put commands to read the port in `if` (with function `canReadLine()`). When I commented the whole condition out leaving just the reading, everything worked fine.